# ipywidgets jupyter notebook

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

[image]

I updated my version of Anaconda and when i try to use ipywidgets in Jupyter notebook i get several graphics instead of an interactive one:

```
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from ipywidgets import interact

def pinta(freq):
    x = np.linspace(0,3,200)
    y = x * np.sin(freq * x)

    plt.plot(x,y,'r')

interact(pinta, freq= (2 * np.pi, 2 * np.pi *10))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `plt.show()` after you call `plt.plot()`.

https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/1181#issuecomment-284172632